# Install postfix with ubuntu autoinstall

Tags: ubuntu, automated-install, debconf

We recently got into ubuntu autoinstall. I planned to install postfix via `packages` and configure the `main.cf` with `sed` in `late-commands` section.

Since postfix installation is interactive I wanted to use `debconf-set-selection` like described here: [Automate the installation of postfix on Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/143968/automate-the-installation-of-postfix-on-ubuntu)

But I think the `apt-get install postfix` collides with the `package` section install of postfix.

Maybe I am able to achieve the debconf changes with the `debconf-selections` section for the autoinstall, but the information: "Users will need to be familiar with the package debconf options." does not really give me the right hint how to set it up.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I use the 22.04 LTS ISO. In the meantime I have installed debconf-tools on a test system to analyze the debconf-selections. The output looks kind of similar to what cannonical describes in the documentation. Couldn't tested it yet but it looks promising.